# ASP NET CORE - Utilização de Session para armazenar listas para evitar acesso ao BD

Tags: session

[image: Essa é a print de uma das tables]Tenho pouca experiência em aplicações Web e estou com essa dúvida.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP NET CORE 3.1, que em uma das páginas tenho 5 tables (BOOTSTRAP) que são preenchidos por consultas ao BD que busca todos os registros de determinado estabelecimento para cada Table, de onde parte o CRUD do sistema.

Acontece que a cada ida e volta a essa página essas consultas são feitas novamente para atualizar a página, causando assim lentidão e muitas requisições ao BD.

Pensei em utilizar Session para armazenar essas listas, mas tenho visto algumas críticas sobre o uso de Session.
Então, gostaria de ajuda para tentar encontrar uma solução que não fere as boas práticas na Web.

Comment: Resolvi minha necessidade utilzando session

Answer (score 0):

Cara, o que você deve fazer é encontrar um componente para o seu front que gerencie a exibição dos dados do backend. Um "datatable on steroids".
Daí você chama sua API de get dos dados e ele exibe os 10 primeiros enquanto ainda baixa o restante.
Agora se a dúvida está em sair da pagina e voltar nela novamente, é natural ele buscar novamente no DB. Caso não queira que isso ocorra, você pode configurar o cache no endpoint de suas APIs, para que consultas feitas dentro de um determinado tempo, não passem da controller, sendo utilizada sempre o resultado obtido anteriormente.

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo de como seria essa configuração do cache do EndPoint?